# Visual Studio 2017 Community verson 15.9.12 Publish results lacks necessary dlls

Tags: windows-10, visual-studio-2010

I have two separate winform projects that I want to publish.  The first project publishes I have successfully and the bin/debug directory contains the exe and all dll files.  The second project indicates that the publish was successful but the bin/debug directory only contains an .exe, .config  and .pdb files.  There are no .dlls included. There must be a hidden switch, or something, that includes/excludes the dlls but I can't find it after several hours searching the web and comparing the two projects.  I have also tried this on vs2019 and get the same conflicting results.  Can you help?

Answer (score 1):

I recently suffered something similar but not so severe...for some reason, I had excluded some files from the project and then I forgot to re-include them. Check Solution Explorer...see if those are Excluded or Included.

This is meant to be a comment because I am not sure if it will work for the OP. However, I don't have the necessary authorization to "comment" on questions.